# A test for even/odd Java

Tags: java, testing, types, integer

Would this test work?:

```
if (testInt/2).ofType(Integer){
    //to-do if even
}
```

I assume it would iff the compiler resolves `testInt/2` before `ofType()`; is this the case??

Comment: Where testInt is of type Integer.

Comment: Why don't you simply do `if(testInt % 2 == 0)` to check even numbers? On the `else` you'd deal with the odds.

Comment: This wouldn't even compile...

Comment: No, it won't work. It will show compile time error as it is not correct syntax to check types in java.

Comment: It looks to me like your if statement has been constructed badly

Comment: `ofType` ??? in java ???? when dereferencing a primitive??? Not a chance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would this test work?

No.  The expression performs integer division (because both operands are integers), and the result of the expression always has type `int`.  So for example

```
   1 / 2 =>  0   // not 0.5
   2 / 2 =>  1   
  -3 / 2 => -2   // not -1.5  or -1 ... 
                 // integer division rounds towards minus infinity
```

> I assume it would iff the compiler resolves testInt/2 before ofType(); is this the case??

The compiler resolves the static type of `testInt/2` at compile time while the `instanceof` test is performed at runtime.

However, your assumption is incorrect because it is based on an incorrect understanding expressions and typing.

- The compile time type of an expression does not depend on the *values* of the operands.  It only depends on the operands' compile-time types.
- For primitive types, there is no polymorphism, so the runtime type and the compile time type are the same.

---

As @Cameron C states, the correct way to do the test is to use the modulus operator `%`.

@styro's approach works, but:

- is it less readable (IMO)
- it is possibly slower
- if it is faster, it *probably* doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4):

Best way to do it is always use the modulus operator.

```
if (testInt % 2 == 0)
{
//Do stuff
}

//3 % 2 = 1  , therefore odd
//4 % 2 = 0  , therefore even
```

Modulus is just getting the remainder from division.

Answer (score 2):

Using the modulus operator works, but there's a better way to check. The least significant bit is 0 for all even numbers, and 1 for odds. Performing a bitwise AND operation with 1, will clear all but the LSB. Check the bit to determine the integer's parity. Less memory is used to clear bits than to compute a remainder.

```
if ((testInt & 1) == 0) //Even Number
if ((testInt & 1) == 1) //Odd Number
/*
  4 & 1 = 0
  5 & 1 = 1
  1342424 & 1 = 0
  5987833 & 1 = 1
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
public static boolean isEven (int testInt) {
    int i=0;
    while (i <= testInt) {
        if (i==testInt) return true;
        i+=2;
    }
    return false;
}
```